# Avoid duplication of toolbar item in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, pde

I have created a toolbar item using eclipse menu contributions and commands.
Using eclipse command core expressions I have bounded the commands to two views (`activePartID` is `viewA` or `viewB`). There is a provision to open `viewB` from `viewA`.

Since I have bounded the command to both the views, when I try to open `viewB` from `viewA`, the toolbar item appears twice. How to refrain it from appearing more than once in the toolbar.

Anyhelp is appreciated.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
     <toolbar
           id="<xyz>.toolbar">
        <command
              commandId="xyz.abc"
              icon="icons/db.jpg"
              id="ABC"
              label="ABC"
              style="push"
              tooltip="ABC">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <and>
                 <with
                       variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                    <equals
                          value="xyz.perspective">
                    </equals>
                 </with>
                 <with
                       variable="activePartId">
                      <or>
                       <equals
                             value="viewA">
                       </equals>
                       <equals
                             value="viewB">
                       </equals>
                    </or>

                 </with>
              </and>
           </visibleWhen>
        </command>
       </toolbar>
     </menuContribution>
 <extension point>
```

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: post `plugin.xml` content

Comment: Hi Chandrayya GK , have posted plugin.xml content here

Comment: Hello everyone, the problem is found to be a configuration error. The current code given above binds a toolbar item to a particular view.Even if the same tool item is bounded to more than one view, it will not be duplicated even if both the views are opened simultaneously. Reason : Eclipse always takes the active view in to account. At a time only a single view will be active.Hence no chance of duplication. Its a good learning for me as well.